# How to remove drivers programmatically in the Shader Editor linked to Geometry nodes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, drivers, shader-nodes

I am struggling with this problem. I am on Windows 10 and using Blender 3.5.1.

The set up is quite simple: I've got two noise textures applied to a plane under "Material". I also created a geometry node system whereby the scale values of both textures are controlled from there (i.e., "copy as new driver" transferred to the scales of the textures). See picture attached.

[image: Geometry Nodes Drivers applied to Shader nodes]

My problem is the following. When I copy the material to another plane (single-user copy), how can I delete the drivers in "Materials.001" using a python script? I don't want for "Material.001" to still be influenced by the geometry node system. Applying the GN system to "Plane.001" doesn't help either.

I have tried this:

```
import bpy

source_mat = bpy.data.materials["Material"] # Material of object "Plane"
copied_mat = source_mat.copy()
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = D.objects["Plane.001"]
bpy.data.objects["Plane.001"].select_set(True)
activeObject = bpy.context.active_object
activeObject.data.materials.append(copied_mat)
```

which simply copies the wanted material to "Plane.001" but I am stuck as to how to remove the drivers.

I can see the drivers using:

```
for m in bpy.data.materials:
    m.name
    if m.use_nodes and m.node_tree.animation_data:
        for d in m.node_tree.animation_data.drivers:
            d.data_path, d.driver.expression
```

which correctly yields

```
'Dots Stroke'
'Material'
('nodes["Voronoi Texture"].inputs[2].default_value', 'Input_2')
('nodes["Voronoi Texture.001"].inputs[2].default_value', 'Input_3')
```

I have seen people removing drivers but it's only on shape keys.

Any help or pointers on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy

node_tree = bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree
node_tree.animation_data_clear()
```